# Android device connecting technologies available for development

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-wifi

I have searched a lot over internet about device to device connecting technologies in other words device to device connection implementation in the concern of hardware and software.

Someone please tell me a whole list of technologies available for the connection between two specific android device, no matter what hardware specification they have in them.

I want a overview over those technology which are used to make data transfer between two devices using wireless connection, Like : Wifi, Bluetooth, etc.

This question i am asking because of client asking me about a "Acoustic sound technology".
I don't know about it and neither i found something related to it.

Help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Now i know that it is **Ultrasonic data transfer** which uses device's mic to generate a sort of sound frequency and get the data on the behalf of that frequency, i don't know exactly about that's why i asked it here.

Sorry if it difficult to understand, I am a little bad at English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware layer of connectivity limited by common device modules: Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, NFC, Camera<->Display and Microphone<->Speaker. Each module has it's own software data transferring methods. I think that your client meant `ultrasonic data transfer`. Basically this method based on high-frequency signals which are emitted by speaker of one device and received by microphone of another device. For instance Yamaha uses ultrasound in [InfoSound](http://www.yamaha.com/products/en/infosound/) technology.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is there any sdk for android or examples for development in android. i will be really thankful to you if you can provide some more details information about this **"ultrasonic data transfer"**.

Comment: @XshivDev There is no official SDK from Google. The task is quite tricky because it demands deep knowledge of sound processing but anyway you could try to find some open source library at github.com for instance. By the way I recommend you to search for not only Java implementations but C/C++ also.

Comment: thanks, you solved some of the problems, now i know what is my question. :P